# Codeigniter Windows to Linux

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

Anyone have idea why on this code:

Controller:

```
class GeneratedInvoices extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("Inv_bg");
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index(){

        $data['invoices'] = $this->Inv_bg->getInvoices();
        $this->load->view('GeneratedInvoices', $data);
    }
}
```

And library

```
public function getLists($type)
    {
        $response = \Httpful\Request::get($this->baseURL. $type)
                    ->authenticateWith($this->username, $this->password)
                    ->sendsJson()
                    ->expectsType("json")
                    ->send();

        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
    public function getInvoices()
    {
        $invoices = $this->getLists("invoices");
        return $invoices['invoices'];
    }
```

Gives me an error such as:

Message: Undefined property: GeneratedInvoices::$Inv_bg

I know that is issue because I worked first on Windows and uploaded this code on a Linux server, but I can't find the error :)

Comment: is your Inv_bg file is also in capital letter?

Comment: And on windows you worked with error_repoting turned off and did not see the warning.

Comment: Please confirm that case is same(Upper case-lower case). Because in linux it is case-sensitive

Comment: i don't know why this was duplicated - because this is mostly CI related it doesn't help op to solve this problem because you've to know the background... - so @u_mulder you should probably reopen it...
@Rade Illijev take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#using-your-class - you've access to the variable only in lowercase form - so `$this->inv_bg->getInvoices();` should do the job